# Difference between launcher and history to bring an activity back to foreground on intent?

Tags: android

What is a difference between launcher(icon at home) and history(recent history) to bring activity back to foreground on intent?

The activity is started by intent that has a **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** flag. So, The activity goes foreground, onNewIntent() will be called.

But, there are some difference when I bring an activity back to foreground from background.

---

Function call sequence:

- Recent history: ***onNewIntent()*** -> ***onRestart()*** -> ***onStart()*** -> ***onResume()***
- Launcher(icon at home): ***onRestart()*** -> ***onStart()*** -> ***onResume()***

Launcher did not call ***onNewIntent()*** function.

What's the mssunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

If I looked at correct methods then `Launcher` calls startActivity only with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, and `RecentsPanelView` calls it with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` , `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. So probably one of this flags is responsible for that behaviour.

Comment: Sorry too late and Thanks. but It's not my solution.